# html2canvas css overflow have no working

Tags: html2canvas

There is a div element, add img Child element with appendChild fun.

div overflow is hidden.

the img display a picture, and can be moved, zoomed and scaled.

if the img is bigger than div, and be moved or zoomed or scaled,

then i use html2canvas to the image, the img have be cut which the size is the same div.

if i set useOverflow true, have the problem

if i set useOverflow false, the img cannot be hidden.

```
html2canvas(document.body, {
            allowTaint: true,
            useCORS: true,
            useOverflow: false,
            onrendered: function (canvas) {
                var blob = canvas.msToBlob();
```

Answer (score 0):

need

```
overflow: hidden;
```

not

```
overflow-x: hidden; overflow-y: hidden;
```